# Graph based question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I recently took a test and got this question. I tried doing it but
>   could not understand it and would really appreciate if you could
>   please explain it to me. Thanks!

The profit of a business is calculated by subtracting expenses from revenue:

Profit = Revenue − Expenses

The firm of Brown and Daughters sells gizmos. The firm has determined that its profit depends on the price for which it sells its gizmos. The relationship between price and profit is shown by the graph below.

[image: graph]

Over what range of prices is the firms revenue greater than its expenses?

1. (a) $-\$500$  to $+\$100$
2. (b) $\$0$  to $\$50$
3. (c) $\$2$  to $\$4.50$
4. (d) $\$20$ to $\$40$
5. (e) $\$20$ to $\$45$

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the range where profits are positive. Upon inspection, it is apparent that the indices on te price axis indicate increments of $5$ in the positive domain. Observing this, by accounting for the increments in the graph, we see the range where profits are positive is $d.(20,45)$.

Comment: Did you mean to write e. $(20, 45)$?